# Trying to set properties/attributes on nested objects with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following code ... I simplified it by not including the `options` in the `select` tags:

```
    <div>
        Show all tasks where assigned to <span><strong></strong>
           <select></select></span>
        and project is <span><strong></strong>
            <select></select></span>
        and status is <span><strong></strong>
            <select></select></span>
        and category is <span><strong></strong>
            <select></select></span>
    </div>
```

When the page loads I would like to do the following:

- Display the text of the selected item in each `select` input between the `strong` tags.
- Hide the `select` tag.

When a user clicks on the `strong` I would like for it to hide `strong` tag and show the `select`.

That being said, I have it working if I assign specific `id` values to each, for lack of a better term, filter. I would like to streamline my jquery so I can avoid the extra HTML.

Hopefully that made some sense ... here is where I am at with my jquery ...

```
$(function () {
    $("#filter select").hide();

    $("#filter strong").each(function () {
        $(this).html($(this).siblings("select:first option:selected").text())); // not working
    });

    $("#filter strong").each(function () {
         $(this).bind("click", function () {
             $(this).css("display", "none"); // not sure if this will work, need to get the first part working
             $(this).siblings("select:first").css("display", "");
         });
    });
});
```

I'm going to keep working on this, but would appreciate any help provided! I think my struggle is with how `sibling` selectors work in jQuery.

### Update

Thanks @alex and @Andy ... here is the final **working** solution:

```
$(function () {
    $("#filter select").hide();

    $("#filter strong").html(function () {
        return $(this).next().find(":selected").text(); 
    })

    $("#filter strong").each(function () {
        $(this).bind("click", function () {
            $(this).css("display", "none");
            $(this).siblings("select:first").css("display", "");
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use:

```
$('strong').click(function(){ $(this).hide().next().show(); });
```

here you have one too many brackets ->  .text());

```
 $("#filter strong").each(function () {
     $(this).html($(this).siblings("select:first option:selected").text())); // not working
 });
```

Comment: Thanks ... I removed the extra bracket ... it still populate the strong tag with the same text, the first select tag.

Comment: you could try it like this: $('strong').html(function(){ return $(this).next().val(); });

Comment: or $('strong').html(function(){ return $(this).next().find(':selected').text(); });

Answer (score 1):

> I think my struggle is with how sibling selectors work in jQuery.

The `siblings()` method will select all elements that are neighbours of the current element. It is essentially the same as...

```
var element = $('#something'),

    siblings = element.parent().children().not(element);
```

You may also be trying to select too much with your selector string passed to `siblings()`.

Try using...

```
.siblings("select:first").find("option:selected")
```

Comment: So let's say I want just the first select sibling for each strong tag ... how would I do that?

Comment: Specifically this code ... $(this).html($(this).siblings("select:first option:selected").text()));

Comment: @mattruma In your case, I would probably use `next('select')`.

Comment: So if you take this code ... $("#filter strong").html("Test"); ... what would you replace the "Test" with to display the text of the selected item of the first select tag that comes after the strong tag? Appreciate your help so far!